# Why am I getting the Heroku welcome screen after I push code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku, web-deployment

I am learning Ruby on Rails using Michael Hartl's [book](https://www.railstutorial.org/book) and I've run into a problem in chapter one while trying to use Heroku to deploy my Hello World App. I keep getting the default welcome screen even though I've used git to push my code to Heroku and my project works fine on localhost.

My routes file is set up like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    root 'application#hello'
end
```

And my controller like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    protect_from_forgery with: :exception

    def hello
        render html: "¡Hola, mundo!"
    end

end
```

I made sure to commit any changes to the git and my directory and I created a new Heroku project in my project directory with:

```
$ heroku login
$ heroku keys:add
$cd /mydirectory
$heroku create
$git push heroku master
```

Everything in git is up to date and I have no idea what else to try. Any ideas?  Thank you.

Comment: Are there any entries in the log? Read it with `heroku logs`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that I had accidentally left SQlite3 in the Gemfile which is not supported by Heroku.

Answer (score 1):

Try following commands:

1. git add .
2. git commit -m "fc"
3. git push heroku master

Comment: This answer would be more helpful if you explained why it works.